# All triangles that have the same orthocenter and circumcircle have the same nine-point circle

Tags: proof-writing, euclidean-geometry, circles, triangles

True or false? Prove it.  I guess it would help to figure out whether 2 triangles can have the same circumcenter or orthocenter and not be congruent.  I have no clue how to figure this out.  If they aren't, then the nine-point circle would have to different.  How would I go about solving this?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "A nine-point circle bisects a line segment going from the corresponding triangle's orthocenter to any point on its circumcircle.", according to Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine-point_circle#Other_properties_of_the_nine-point_circle

Comment: Yo mean "have the same circumcenter AND the same orthocenter", I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

True. Let $H -$ orthocenter and $O -$ circumcenter, $R -$ radius, $F -$ midpoint $HO$. Then nine-point circle has a center point $F$ and a radius $\frac 12 R$